# How does the EntranceThemeTransition from LayoutRootStyle cascade to child controls?

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I'm going through the [WinRT-XAML tutorials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211380.aspx) at the moment, and I cannot figure out why the WebView control doesn't do the same entrance animation as the other controls. There is a section on `Adding animations and transitions` which explains that it is not expected to and that a Storyboard with animation is needed to do that.

I've found the source of the setter that applies the transition to the other controls in StandardStyles.xaml.

```
<Style x:Key="LayoutRootStyle" TargetType="Panel">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="ChildrenTransitions">
        <Setter.Value>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <EntranceThemeTransition/>
            </TransitionCollection>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

It seems like this should apply the EntranceThemeTransition to every child control of a panel with this style - or it should only apply the transition to its direct children. It seems to be doing a bit of both.

Also I expected controls that do not have any positioning information to be animated along with their parents. That doesn't seem to be the case, the direct parent of the WebView animates just fine.

What makes WebView so special in this case? Apart from the fact that it isn't part of the default template. Why do we need to add a PopInThemeAnimation and Storyboard to get this one control to move and why does it move at a different speed to the control it is supposed to be inside!?

Answer (score 2):

A `WebView` is a special control that lives in its own HWND (classic WinAPI window) as opposed to the rest of the typical XAML-based UI rendered in a depth-wise flat space (a jupiter Window). As such it lives in its own airspace (bing it up) on top of all the other controls. You usually replace it with some other control (e.g. Rectangle) filled with a `WebViewBrush` sync'd to the WebView when you want to animate it or overlay some other content on top of it (e.g. an app bar).

I think the (some) theme animations use [Windows Animation Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371981%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or some other mechanism instead of regular Storyboards and it is possible the WebView control just doesn't work well with it.

My advice would be - if it doesn't work with what you are trying to use (EntranceThemeTransition) - use something different (a regular Storyboard-based animation).

Comment: So normal behavior is for all child controls of the layoutroot to animate the same way apart from certain controls like WebView that don't play nicely. Is that right? Any other controls that you know of that don't work well?

Comment: MediaElement behaves a bit better, but you still have to be careful with it when playing a video.